# Why did I lose 6 reputation without any record of it?

Tags: support, reputation

This all started from the day before yesterday. I logged into my account and found out 2 reputation was gone. I checked my reputation changes, but didn't find any record. The same thing occurred yesterday and today.

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you check 'show removed posts'? If you edit any question that gets removed, you lose the 2 reputation for it.

Comment: Visit your reputation history and make sure the "show removed posts" box is checked at the bottom. Three posts which you had suggested edits on previously got deleted by an automated process, and you lost the +2 reputation for each of them.

Comment: Alright Thanks. Already seen the reason